# Select 4 last digits in any string

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm having an array of various string and I need to select from each of the strings last 4 digits that are not separated.

var example = ["eg3322-3748", "eg3322-3749_ABCD", "eg3750_5GHJ"];

The desired result should give these results:

var example = ["3748", "3749", "3750"]

Thanks! :)

Comment: Does 'separation' mean 'affixed with _' ?

Comment: @collapsar Nope. That won't work. OP has both `-` and `_`. But the point is, no effort is shown, so we cannot make any assumptions

Comment: @GalAbra That won't be enough, eg. `eg3750_5GHJ` would produce `7505`.

Comment: @Rajesh Maybe it would - it seems that the OP wants to extract the last 4 digits after removal of a suffix starting with `_`. As you say, it is wild guessing only for a 'do my job' request ...

Comment: @collapsar I have added an answer. Hope that addresses your queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```js
const input = ['eg3322-3748', 'eg3322-3749_ABCD', 'eg3750_5GHJ'];

const result = input.map(item => 
  item
    .split('').reverse().join('') // Reverse string
    .match(/\d{4}/)[0]            // Find first 4 consecutive digits
    .split('').reverse().join('') // Reverse matches back
);

console.log(result);
```

PS: next time you ask a question, please show what you attempted. Thanks!

**Edit**: this will generate an error if any string does not contain 4 consecutive digits. You can easily fix that by adding a fallback to `match` (with `['']`, for instance, then it'll return that).

Comment: What will be the result of `eg3750_1234`?

Comment: Well, `1234`. Should always retrieve the last 4 consecutive digits.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! Not sure if its worth just showing a lot of useless attempts.

Answer (score 1):

#### Logic:

- Based on given data, its obvious, you are looking for a batch of alphanumeric/numeric characters and wish to get last 4 digits.
- So you can create a regex that matches all such groups, and returns last one.
- Then, from this last group, just extract last 4 characters and Ta-da!!!

```js
var example = ["eg3322-3748", "eg3322-3749_ABCD", "eg3750_5GHJ"];
var regex = /([a-z]*\d{4,})/g;

var output = example.map((str) => {
  const match = str.match(regex).pop();
  return match.substr(-4);
});

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use .substr() function to slice the length of string. Maybe "example(i).substr(example(i).length - 4)" will work.

Comment: You ignore the `_`-initiated suffixes and the that digits occur contigously. Won't even work with the samples  provided.

Comment: I think you are right. This is code is just valid to select last 4 entries of the string.